# Boot partition for Software RAID 1

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, raid-1

According to this tutorial:

http://edoceo.com/howto/mdadm-raid1

as well as the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/821307/how-to-proceed-after-creating-software-raid-1-array-on-linux),

...it is necessary to create a separate boot partition if you want to boot from a software RAID 1 array on Linux (an array created via `mdadm`).  My question is:

1. Is this correct?
2. If so, why is this necessary?  Why can't there be a single primary bootable partition (mounted on `/`) on both drives in the RAID 1 array?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally true that you need a separate /boot unless you want to boot the system on a single of the two RAID1 disks and then remount as md after the system is running or set up an appropriate initramfs.

From [mdadm wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm):

> Since support for MD is found in the kernel, there is an issue with
>   using it before the kernel is running. Specifically it will not be
>   present if the boot loader is either (e)LiLo or GRUB legacy. It may
>   not be present for GRUB 2. In order to circumvent this problem a /boot
>   filesystem must be used either without md support, or else with RAID1.
>   In the latter case the system will boot by treating the RAID1 device
>   as a normal filesystem, and once the system is running it can be
>   remounted as md and the second disk added to it. This will result in a
>   catch-up, but /boot filesystems are usually small.
>
> With more recent bootloaders it is possible to load the MD support as
>   a kernel module through the initramfs mechanism, this approach allows
>   you to let the /boot filesystem be inside any RAID system without the
>   need of a complex manual configuration.

Although it isn't your question, it may be useful to consult [RAID Boot](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Boot) for more information on using initramfs to start a system booting from md volumes.

Comment: It seems this doesn't work for EFI System Partitions though?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai AFAIK the EFI System Partition has to be the first physical partition on a hard disk and can not be on a software RAID array.

Comment: https://outflux.net/blog/archives/2018/04/19/uefi-booting-and-raid1/